# Unable to leave the loop

Tags: python, loops

I've checked the program all over again and again, but I still can't understand why I can't leave the loop after I've entered 'n'. The boolean value of 'end' should be determined by the 'y' or 'n' the user has chosen. However, every time I hit 'n' or 'y', the loop just keep going on. This is not the whole program, I only pick the part which might be related to the problem here.

```
def k(response):

    while response !='y' and response!='n':
        response=input("Would you like to do again (y/n)")
    if response=='y':
        end= False
    elif response=='n':
        end= True
    return end


end=False

while not end:

    year=int(input("Year of birth:"))
    y(year)

    month=int(input("Month of birth:"))
    m(month)

    day=int(input("Day of birth:"))
    d(day)

    j(month)
    response=input("Would you like to do again (y/n)")
    k(response)

    end
```

Comment: Check your indentation. The code at the moment never checks what `response` is. If your indentation is actually correct, please edit your question with the correct formatting.

Comment: Format your code!!

Comment: The formatting is a bit difficult to read. It's hard to tell without a little more context, but my first thought is that you should set `end=k(response)` rather than just `k(response)` in your main loop. Otherwise `end` does not get updated.

Comment: please fix your code in this question - it is not clear what this code does

Comment: This code doesn't run with your current indentation. You have an empty function (which is a syntax error), then a while loop which will run forever, then two if checks, then a return outside a function (which is also not allowed)

Comment: I do check the indentation of the code before I posted here, but the format  somehow went wrong here. I've tried to get the function and while loop inside the code blocks, but I don't undertstand why they can't be embedded in them.  I think the reason why the loop doesn't stop is that the 'end' boolean is not updated. However, why can't end be updated after I've called k(response), which will return the new boolean value of end?

Comment: I edited your post to fix the indentation issue, it should show up as soon as the review went through.

Also, your hunch is right. Variables in other functions are in a different namespace, so setting `end` to a value there does not suffice unless it is defined as global. You need to assign the returned result to the variable `end` in the main namespace as well.

Comment: Do not worry, by the way, the code indentation in StackOverflow needs some getting used to but is great, once you learned how to use it. Best to paste all the code, then later mark it all completely and use the "Code" button in the editor.

Comment: Why You Check one Response two times in different conditions?response !='y' and response!='n'

Comment: @VanessaHuang I enhanced my answer to your question to contain a brief explanation of why your code did not work. The code in the answer was tested on my computer locally and worked fine for me.

Comment: @ingofreyer thanks a lot, now I understand why the 'end' variable in the function can't update the value in the while loop. I tried your code, and it worked on my cp too!

Comment: @VanessaHuang glad to hear that. Feel free to ask further questions, if necessary. If my answer was helpful to you, I would be happy if you could mark it as the correct answer. This would help future users to directly find the answer to their problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, most of the program (once the indentation issue is worked out, which I think is a StackOverflow rendering issue, I suggested an edit to your question which fixed that) is working fine.
However, you return a variable in function `k()`, apparently expecting to change the variable in your main code by that. This is not the case, you need to assign it properly.

As soon as you assign it properly, it works fine.
I took the freedom to also fix the whitespace in your code to improve readability and adhere to PEP8:

```
def k(response):
    while response != 'y' and response != 'n':
        response = input("Would you like to do again (y/n)")
    if response == 'y':
        end = False
    elif response == 'n':
        end = True
    return end


end = False

while not end:
    year = int(input("Year of birth:"))
    print(year)

    month = int(input("Month of birth:"))
    print(month)

    day = int(input("Day of birth:"))
    print(day)

    print(month)
    response = input("Would you like to do again (y/n)")
    end = k(response)
```

For testing, I replaced your additional function calls with `print`.
Your code is also only working in Python 3, if you want to use it in Python 2.7, you need to replace `input()` with `raw_input()`

So why did your previous code not work exactly? Variables have limited visibility (scopes or namespaces, depending on the language). In this case, variables assigned in the function `k()` do not influence the variables in outer scope (otherwise, you would need to be really careful about your variable names). If you want to transfer the value of a variable in the function scope, you either define it as global (one should avoid this, since it often leads to chaos) or you return its value. However, someone using your function does not know the variable names or might not even care about the returned value. Thus, if someone wants to use this value, they have to assign it to a variable of their choice. Otherwise, the value is lost. In this case, you needed to assign it again to your variable `end`.